# Array of objects as session variable symfony

Tags: arrays, symfony, session, object

I'm trying set a varible session with an array of objects in a Symfony Controller. I had tried `$session->set('expedients', serialize($expedients));` and `$session->set('expedients', $expedients);` too; but the next step, when I go to get the variable into a new variable in another controller, what I must do to get the original array of objects? My result by the moment is: `

```
object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)#923 (9) { 
    ["snapshot":"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":private]=> array(0) { } 
    ["owner":"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":private]=> NULL 
    ["association":"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":private]=> NULL 
    ["em":"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":private]=> NULL 
    ["backRefFieldName":"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":private]=> NULL 
    ["typeClass":"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":private]=> NULL 
    ["isDirty":"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":private]=> bool(false) 
    ["collection":protected]=> object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)#925 (1) { 
    ["elements":"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":private]=> array(0) { } }
    ["initialized":protected]=> bool(false)
}
```

Comment: IMHO is not a good idea to store in session an PersistentCollection object.  Try with a simple ArrayCollection by calling `$session->set('expedients', $expedients->toArray());`

Comment: Better save some simple data (as an integer), and then (in the another controller) recovery by that integer value with a new database query, for example?

Comment: Yes @Drako more better, when you persist a doctrine object usually you lose the related object also

Comment: `->toArray()` work but not quite; take your option ;-) Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Drako you are welcome, consider to post your solution as answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

As @Matteo said, `->toArray();` can work (more or less) but better is save some simple data (as an integer), and then (in the another controller) recovery by that integer value with a new database query. Thanks again.